# disassemble and reassemble strings based on list

Tags: python, string, nltk

I have four speakers like this:

`Team_A=[Fred,Bob]`

`Team_B=[John,Jake]`

They are having a conversation and it is all represented by a string, ie. `convo`=

```
Fred
hello

John
hi

Bob
how is it going?

Jake
we are doing fine
```

How do I disassemble and reassemble the string so I can split it into 2 strings, 1 string of what `Team_A` said, and 1 string from what `Team_A` said?

output: `team_A_said="hello how is it going?"`, `team_B_said="hi we are doing fine"`

The lines don't matter.

I have this awful `find`... then `slice` code that is not scalable. Can someone suggest something else? Any libraries to help with this?

I didn't find anything in `nltk` library

Comment: Does the `convo` string always consist of blocks of the form `name\nstuff they said\n\n`? Will it only contain 1 block for each person, or can there be a large number of blocks?

Comment: yes, it is always in this format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code assumes that contents of `convo` *strictly* conforms to the
`name\nstuff they said\n\n`
pattern. The only tricky code it uses is `zip(*[iter(lines)]*3)`, which creates a list of triplets of strings from the `lines` list. For a discussion on this technique and alternate techniques, please see [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/4014959).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

team_ids = ('A', 'B')

team_names = (
    ('Fred', 'Bob'),
    ('John', 'Jake'),
)

#Build a dict to get team name from person name
teams = {}
for team_id, names in zip(team_ids, team_names):
    for name in names:
        teams[name] = team_id


#Each block in convo MUST consist of <name>\n<one line of text>\n\n
#Do NOT omit the final blank line at the end
convo = '''Fred
hello

John
hi

Bob
how is it going?

Jake
we are doing fine

'''

lines = convo.splitlines()

#Group lines into <name><text><empty> chunks
#and append the text into the appropriate list in `said`
said = {'A': [], 'B': []}
for name, text, _ in zip(*[iter(lines)]*3):
    team_id = teams[name]
    said[team_id].append(text)

for team_id in team_ids:
    print 'Team %s said: %r' % (team_id, ' '.join(said[team_id]))
```

**output**

```
Team A said: 'hello how is it going?'
Team B said: 'hi we are doing fine'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to split up each entry. `itertools.ifilter` can then be used to extract the required entries for each conversation.

```
import itertools
import re

def get_team_conversation(entries, team):
    return [e for e in itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x.split('\n')[0] in team, entries)]

Team_A = ['Fred', 'Bob']
Team_B = ['John', 'Jake']

convo = """
Fred
hello

John
hi

Bob
how is it going?

Jake
we are doing fine"""

find_teams = '^(' + '|'.join(Team_A + Team_B) + r')$'
entries = [e[0].strip() for e in re.findall('(' + find_teams + '.*?)' + '(?=' + find_teams + r'|\Z)', convo, re.S+re.M)]

print 'Team-A', get_team_conversation(entries, Team_A)
print 'Team-B', get_team_conversation(entries, Team_B)
```

Giving the following output:

```
Team-A ['Fred\nhello', 'Bob\nhow is it going?']
Team_B ['John\nhi', 'Jake\nwe are doing fine']
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem of language parsing.

*Answer is a Work in progress*

## Finite state machine

A conversation transcript can be understood by imagining it as parsed by automata with the following states :

```
[start]  ---> [Name]----> [Text]-+----->[end]
               ^                 |
               |                 | (whitespaces)
               +-----------------+
```

You can parse your conversation by making it follow that state machine. If your parsing succeeds (ie. follows the states to end of text) you can browse your "conversation tree" to derive meaning.

#### Tokenizing your conversation (lexer)

You need functions to recognize the `name` state. This is straightforward

```
name = (Team_A | Team_B) + '\n'
```

#### Conversation alternation

In this answer, I did not assume that a conversation involves alternating between the people speaking, like this conversation would :

```
Fred     # author 1
hello

John     # author 2
hi

Bob      # author 3
how is it going ?

Bob      # ERROR : author 3 again !
are we still on for saturday, Fred ?
```

This might be problematic if your transcript concatenates answers from same author

Comment: but don't you first have to find and slice everything? then reassemble it?

Comment: Not directly : You only go through the text once while following the automata (and check for inclusion of text in given names, not calling `find`), whereas the find / slice method is more on the quadratic lookup side of things (looking all around the text backwards and forward). Does that answer your question ?